# Storybook - Cannot Mock a Nested React-Router-Dom Link without throwing endless NPM errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, storybook

I am trying to implement StorybookJS into a SSR React app. Basic components work fine (button, headers etc). But anything that *nests* using dependencies like `react-router-dom` breaks.

Example:
We have a custom built `<Link />` component that manages external links with a ternary. The external links flip to `<a href=` while internals use react-router-dom's `<Link>` imported as `<ReactLink />`. That code is like this:

```
// src/client/components/link/Link.js 

import { Link as ReactLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { isLinkExternal } from "services/utils";

export const Link = ({ href, children = null, ...props }) => {

  return isLinkExternal(href) ? (
    <a href={href} {...props}>
      {children}
    </a>
  ) : (
    <ReactLink to={href} {...props}>
      {children}
    </ReactLink>
  );
};
```

The StorybookJS file for it looks like this:-

```
// link.stories.js

import React from "react";
import { Link } from "./Link"; // importing my component

export default {
  title: "My Components/Link",
  component: Link, // assigning my component
};

export const MyStoryBookLink = () => <Link href="/foo">I am a link</Link>;
```

Now, when i run Storybook it throws a load of errors, here are the recurring/main ones:-

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/redis-parser/lib/hiredis.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hiredis' in '/Users/me/Documents/my-proj/node_modules/redis-parser/lib'
...
...
@ ./.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
```

I haven't touched anything redis / hiredis related and there is no such file as `generated-stories-entry.js`. The app works perfectly in Dev and Production so this is exclusively a Storybook env issue.

Next error down:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cache-manager-ioredis/node_modules/ioredis/lib/connectors/connector.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/me/Documents/myProject/node_modules/cache-manager-ioredis/node_modules/ioredis/lib/connectors'
```

Again, Though we *are* using `cache-manager-ioredis`, no idea why this is suddenly missing a module if it works fine on the app itself and all i'm trying to do is render a .

Next one:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in cache-manager-ioredis
```

Same thing again^^

Then i get a load of these:

```
     /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis doesn't exist
            .mjs
              /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis.js doesn't exist
            .jsx
              /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis.jsx doesn't exist
            .ts
              /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis.tsx doesn't exist
            .json
              /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis.json doesn't exist
            .cjs
              /Users/me/Documents/myProj/__mocks__/hiredis.cjs doesn't exist
```

Suggests it's looking for mocks to cover these sub sub sub dependencies, wherever they're needed.

I get the same for `net` and `tls`.

Finally, I get some:

```
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

I'm thinking somewhere in the depths of using `react-router-dom/Link` it is trying to find these, and they would only be there if webpack dev server / hot reloading made them accessible, OR if they were transpiled to be accessible from the production bundle.

But how do I mock these out? And is there an easy way to do it rather than manually mocking every sub dependency?

I have tried:

1. adding `__mocks__/react-router-dom.js` with an `export const Link = ({props}) => <div>{children}</div>` but it doesnt seem to kick in.
2. adding `alias` logic to `.storybook/main.js`:

```
webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias['react-router-dom'] = require.resolve('../__mocks__/react-router-dom.js');
    return config;
  },
```

Again, nothing seems to change.

3. using the `storybook-react-router` pkg but this seems quite old now, it configs to an old `config.js` file rather than `main.js` and uses the older `storiesOf` syntax. Also couldn't get to do anything.
4. manually installed `tls`, `hiredis` etc as `--save-dev` dependencies. But this seems hack. Why are these modules missing?

I cannot believe Storybook is this hard to use, more likely I'm overlooking something. I just want to mock something as common and basic as a  from RRD.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: do you ever find an answer? I have similar issue but using Angular. I use SSR as well. I think somehow it has something to do with nodejs

Comment: I'm afraid not, bud.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason. It is because of node.js packages. To make it work, there are 2 solutions.

1. avoid importing node.js packages (usually related to SSR) for storybook related code. I use NX to structure my code, so I can easily move those part to its own library and only reference it from the top. (No storybook for the top App either in this solution)
2. skip those packages in the config.

something like

```js
config.resolve.fallback = { http: false, net: false, tls: false, fs: false, dns: false, path: false };
```